# Deciphering exactly what function calls a smart contract deployer made to his contracts?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, decode, smartcontracts, function-call

I am forking am Open Sourced DeFi Project. After modifying everything in the frontend, i now just need to Deploy the Smart Contracts, which is an autonomous Ecosystem of Contracts that run themselves with minimal setup after deployment. However, they are only setup and in turn run themselves after you make several function calls to some of the contracts (setting a variable to point to an address, setting a variable to a startTime, etc).

I cannot figure out exactly what these Deployers of the same ecosystem of contracts are doing (what function calls they're making with what variables after deployment).

I have used the appropriate BlockChain's blockscan site (AVAX, snowtrace.io), in order to figure out what order they deploy the contracts in - and i can see SOME of the function calls they make but the variables are not always able to have the "date decoded", and the "Method" is not always listed either, etc. Is their something I don't understand or that I am doing wrong in order to figure this out? I am new to all of this. The Open Source Project has no README or GUIDE explaining a damn thing about a damn thing, I've so far had to figure out everything front and backend 100% by myself, and now that it's down to the wire with the whole Dapp being finished, with only function calls left in my way.